# How can I use Meta-SGD with U-Net? A network with a lot of layers and weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradient-descent, conv-neural-network

I'm using this:

```
Python version: 3.7.7 (default, May  6 2020, 11:45:54) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
TensorFlow version: 2.1.0
Eager execution: True
```

With a U-Net model with this summary:

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 200, 200, 1) 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_1 (Conv2D)                (None, 200, 200, 64) 1664        input_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_2 (Conv2D)                (None, 200, 200, 64) 102464      conv1_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool1 (MaxPooling2D)            (None, 100, 100, 64) 0           conv1_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2_1 (Conv2D)                (None, 100, 100, 96) 55392       pool1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2_2 (Conv2D)                (None, 100, 100, 96) 83040       conv2_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool2 (MaxPooling2D)            (None, 50, 50, 96)   0           conv2_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3_1 (Conv2D)                (None, 50, 50, 128)  110720      pool2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3_2 (Conv2D)                (None, 50, 50, 128)  147584      conv3_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool3 (MaxPooling2D)            (None, 25, 25, 128)  0           conv3_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv4_1 (Conv2D)                (None, 25, 25, 256)  295168      pool3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv4_2 (Conv2D)                (None, 25, 25, 256)  1048832     conv4_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool4 (MaxPooling2D)            (None, 12, 12, 256)  0           conv4_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_1 (Conv2D)                (None, 12, 12, 512)  1180160     pool4[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_2 (Conv2D)                (None, 12, 12, 512)  2359808     conv5_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_conv5 (UpSampling2D)         (None, 24, 24, 512)  0           conv5_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
crop_conv4 (Cropping2D)         (None, 24, 24, 256)  0           conv4_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 24, 24, 768)  0           up_conv5[0][0]
                                                                 crop_conv4[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv6_1 (Conv2D)                (None, 24, 24, 256)  1769728     concatenate[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv6_2 (Conv2D)                (None, 24, 24, 256)  590080      conv6_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_conv6 (UpSampling2D)         (None, 48, 48, 256)  0           conv6_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
crop_conv3 (Cropping2D)         (None, 48, 48, 128)  0           conv3_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 48, 48, 384)  0           up_conv6[0][0]
                                                                 crop_conv3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv7_1 (Conv2D)                (None, 48, 48, 128)  442496      concatenate_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv7_2 (Conv2D)                (None, 48, 48, 128)  147584      conv7_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_conv7 (UpSampling2D)         (None, 96, 96, 128)  0           conv7_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
crop_conv2 (Cropping2D)         (None, 96, 96, 96)   0           conv2_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 96, 96, 224)  0           up_conv7[0][0]
                                                                 crop_conv2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv8_1 (Conv2D)                (None, 96, 96, 96)   193632      concatenate_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv8_2 (Conv2D)                (None, 96, 96, 96)   83040       conv8_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_conv8 (UpSampling2D)         (None, 192, 192, 96) 0           conv8_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
crop_conv1 (Cropping2D)         (None, 192, 192, 64) 0           conv1_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_3 (Concatenate)     (None, 192, 192, 160 0           up_conv8[0][0]
                                                                 crop_conv1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv9_1 (Conv2D)                (None, 192, 192, 64) 92224       concatenate_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv9_2 (Conv2D)                (None, 192, 192, 64) 36928       conv9_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv9_3 (ZeroPadding2D)         (None, 200, 200, 64) 0           conv9_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv10_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 200, 200, 1)  65          conv9_3[0][0]
==================================================================================================
Total params: 8,740,609
Trainable params: 8,740,609
Non-trainable params: 0
```

And with this implementation:

```
inputs = Input(shape=img_shape)

    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv1_1')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv1_2')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", name='pool1')(conv1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv2_1')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv2_2')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", name='pool2')(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv3_1')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv3_2')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", name='pool3')(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv4_1')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (4, 4), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv4_2')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", name='pool4')(conv4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv5_1')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv5_2')(conv5)

    up_conv5 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", name='up_conv5')(conv5)
    ch, cw = get_crop_shape(conv4, up_conv5)
    crop_conv4 = Cropping2D(cropping=(ch, cw), data_format="channels_last", name='crop_conv4')(conv4)
    up6 = concatenate([up_conv5, crop_conv4])
    conv6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv6_1')(up6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv6_2')(conv6)

    up_conv6 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", name='up_conv6')(conv6)
    ch, cw = get_crop_shape(conv3, up_conv6)
    crop_conv3 = Cropping2D(cropping=(ch, cw), data_format="channels_last", name='crop_conv3')(conv3)
    up7 = concatenate([up_conv6, crop_conv3])
    conv7 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv7_1')(up7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv7_2')(conv7)

    up_conv7 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", name='up_conv7')(conv7)
    ch, cw = get_crop_shape(conv2, up_conv7)
    crop_conv2 = Cropping2D(cropping=(ch, cw), data_format="channels_last", name='crop_conv2')(conv2)
    up8 = concatenate([up_conv7, crop_conv2])
    conv8 = Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv8_1')(up8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv8_2')(conv8)

    up_conv8 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_last", name='up_conv8')(conv8)
    ch, cw = get_crop_shape(conv1, up_conv8)
    crop_conv1 = Cropping2D(cropping=(ch, cw), data_format="channels_last", name='crop_conv1')(conv1)
    up9 = concatenate([up_conv8, crop_conv1])
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv9_1')(up9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format="channels_last", name='conv9_2')(conv9)

    ch, cw = get_crop_shape(inputs, conv9)
    conv9 = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(ch, cw), data_format="channels_last", name='conv9_3')(conv9)
    conv10 = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid', data_format="channels_last", name='conv10_1')(conv9)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=conv10)
```

To compile the model I do:

```
model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=(1e-4) * 2), loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I have understood how MAML or Meta-SGD works, but I don't know to use it with a network with a lot of layers and weights.

On this [Github](https://github.com/sudharsan13296/Hands-On-Meta-Learning-With-Python/blob/master/06.%20MAML%20and%20it%27s%20Variants/6.5%20Building%20MAML%20From%20Scratch.ipynb), there is an implementation of MAML.

The first thing that I don't know how to know it is this line of code from the previous Github:

```
#randomly initialize our model parameter theta
self.theta = np.random.normal(size=50).reshape(50, 1)
```

Here, there are 50 weights. But I don't know how many weights are in the network, and their shape.

And I don't know if I have use MAML on each layer separately or use it on all layers at once.

Or how is the format for a HDF5 file.

How can I use MAML or Meta-SGD with U-Net?

Comment: You need to define your own optimizer instead of using Adam to compile your model. Meta-SGD uses a vector for an adaptive learning rate instead of a scalar, and this doesn't seem to be implemented in Keras. Here's an (oldish) example on how to implement an optimizer: https://github.com/Arturus/kaggle-web-traffic/blob/master/cocob.py